# While loop not checking both conditions?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am fairly new to programming and have decided to take on a project where I create a game in the console. The user has the options to move up, down, left, or right from the center of an area that is a 3x3 grid. One of the x,y locations is marked a 'bad' square and the game ends when the user's x and y are equal to that of the bad square's. The bad squares location is `x = 1` and `y = 3`.

The problem I have is that when the user enters Up or Left (hence the users y becomes 3 or the users x becomes 1) and the game ends even though one of the other axis values does not match the bad squares.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[]args){
    //scanner
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    //string that will get users value
    String movement;

    //strings that are compared to users to determine direction
    String up = "Up";
    String down = "Down";
    String left = "Left";
    String right = "Right";

    //starting coordinates of user
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;

    //coordinates of bad square
    int badx = 1;
    int bady = 3;

    //message telling user options to move (not very specific yet)
    System.out.println("Up, Down, Left, Right");

    //do while loop that continues until 
    do {
        movement = userIn.nextLine();

        //checking user input and moving them accordingly
        if (movement.equals(up)) {
            y++;
        } else if (movement.equals(down)) {
            y--;
        } else if (movement.equals(left)) {
            x--;
        } else if (movement.equals(right)) {
            x++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unacceptable value");
        }

        //checking if user is out of bounds, if user tries to leave area, x or y is increased or decreased accordingly
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 3 || y > 3) {
            System.out.println("Out of bounds");
            if (x < 0) {
                x++;
            } else if (y < 0) {
                y++;
            } else if (x > 3) {
                x--;
            } else if (y > 3) {
                y--;
            }
        }
        //message showing user x and y coordinates
        System.out.println("x =" + x + " y =" + y);
    } while (y != bady && x != badx); //what checks to see if user has come across the bad square

    //ending message (game ends)
    System.out.println("Bad Square. Game over.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while(y != bady && x != badx)` test tests `y` isn't bad AND `x` isn't bad therefore it only takes one of these to be `false` for your loop to cease.

An easy fix might be to swap your logic around a little.

`while(!(y == bady && x == badx))`

Answer (score 1):

If you think about how your conditional statement is phrased `while(y != bady && x != badx)` you will see that when either `x = 1` or `y = 3`, one of the sides in the AND statement evaluates to false and causes the whole condition to be false. You could handle it by instead writing:

```
while(y != bady || x != badx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set logic OR in condition
while(y != bady || x != badx);

&& matters that both conditions should be true